# Как в манифесте запросить работу на системных страницах?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, chrome-extension, extension

Есть ли возможность указать все страницы, включая системные, в `content_scripts`?
Сейчас использую `"matches": ["<all_urls>"]`, на всех обычных страницах всё хорошо, но не работает с системными страницами, кодированными картинками (`data:image/png;base64,...`) и даже на странице магазина приложений хрома.

Я делаю переводчик и переводы мне могут потребоваться не только на обычных страницах.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Доступные протоколы: `http`, `https`, `file`, `ftp` и среди них нет `chrome`.

Поэтому обычными средствами нельзя получить доступ к `chrome://` страницам.

Однако, можно разрешить доступ с этим страницам, включив настройку `chrome://flags/#extensions-on-chrome-urls`.

Но необходимо вручную указать к каким страницам нужен доступ, без заглушек типа `chrome://*` и убедить клиента в необходимости включения настройки.

<sup>По мотивам вопроса: [Can you access chrome:// pages from an extension?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19042857/6275986)</sup>